# Selenium Select Frame takes very long time to complete

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, google-chrome-headless

Environment:
`Chrome Driver 92.0.4515`

I found that `selenium.select_frame` takes nearly 3 minutes to switch between main window to the frame

The issue only occurs with `headless` chrome, the normal chrome's still working fine.

Any solutions will be highly appreciated! Thank you!

My webdriver's arguments:

```
        options.add_argument(f"--window-size={width},{height}")
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_argument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
                             "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36 Edg/84.0.522.59")
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
```

Comment: What are your options for webdriver options

Comment: @theNishant I've updated the options, thank you!

Comment: You are stating that have a problem with chromedriver 92.0.4515 but in your user agent argument you use Chrome/84.0.4147.125. Not sure if this is related or not. Check if your chrome version is also 92.0.4515. And on the first line from your code I think that you should delete the f letter right after the opening bracket. Can you also update the question with the full build number of chrome driver, chrome, operating system.